# How to add default SNS topic policy using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-sns

Hi I added a SNS topic using CDK and attached a custom policy statement like this:

```js
const snsTopic = new Topic(this, 'SnsTopic');
const snsTopicPolicyStatement = new PolicyStatement({
  effect: Effect.ALLOW,
  actions: ['SNS:Publish'],
  principals: [
    new ArnPrincipal('arn:xxx'),
    new ArnPrincipal('arn:xxx'),
  ],
  resources: ['SNS_TOPIC_ARN'],
});
snsTopicPolicyStatement.sid = 'publishStatementId';
snsTopic.addToResourcePolicy(snsTopicPolicyStatement);
```

But this is somehow the only access policy this topic has, whereas if I just create a new Topic and not attach any custom policy, it would look something like:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:xxx",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "xxx"
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

So I was wondering how to add this default access policy and the custom one at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than create your own Policy Statement can you use the built in [grantPublish](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_sns.Topic.html#grantwbrpublishgrantee) method?

```js
const topic = new Topic(this, 'MyTopic')
topic.grantPublish(new ArnPrincipal('arn:xxx'))
topic.grantPublish(new ArnPrincipal('arn:yyy'))
```